# Do I need boot partition on UEFI & Luks?

Tags: gentoo, luks, uefi

I'm trying to install Gentoo on LUKS partition (simple layout - single root partition, without underlying LVM).

Right now it works, but I doubt if I done it properly. I've got such a partitions:

First of all SSD - sda

- `/dev/sda1` `/boot/efi`
- `/dev/sda2` `/boot`
- `/dev/sda3` - LUKS (`/dev/mapper/root` mounted as `/`)
- `/dev/sda4` - future Windows

There is also HDD - sdb, which will be probably LUKS mounted as `/home/user/data`.

First of all - do I need /dev/sda2? Is it necessary, to have an unencrypted boot, if I'm booting from UEFI?

Secondly. Is is possible to decrypt `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2` with the same passphrase as`/dev/sda3` without writing it twice?

And thirdly - does this layout make any sense on a SSD/HDD tandem?

Answer (score 2):

- First, Is mandatory has a unencrypted /boot partition.
- Third, of course. It is a really good choose.

The second question, I do not have a answer. But I think who you must retype the password three times.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a FAT32-formatted GPT partition with "EFI System Partition" type (the particular GUID might be represented differently within various tools, e.g. "boot" flag in `parted`); see also [this introduction](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html).

PS: your question was quite hard to read and understand, did you understand what you wanted to ask in the first place?..

Comment: It looks that something went wrong with formatting my question. I've asked if I have to create an additional unencrypted `/boot` partition, or I can rely on EFI partition and place kernel/initramfs on EFI.

Comment: Depends on what sits in your `/boot/efi`: if you've got kernel image (and probably initrd) there, chances are that you might not need an extra cleartext `/boot`; but if your EFI boot scheme only puts the bootloader (and maybe its config file) there, then you still need it.
I'd rather make one just in case, maybe with a swap partition next to it so `/boot` could be merged into swap if proved unneeded by experiment (but ALT Linux EFI boot scheme means minimal `/boot/efi` use).